# Is it possible to modify a WearableDrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

My app keeps getting rejected by Google testers because it uses a [`WearableDrawerLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/widget/drawer/WearableDrawerLayout), which is the WearOS equivalent of a `NavigationDrawer`. It's a built-in menu that you can pull up from the bottom or top. You can see it in action [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/how-to-improve-app-design-for-wear-20.html). When the drawer is full screen it looks like an `Activity` with scrollable content.

It is WearOS policy that all `Activities` have a black background, a scrollbar and respond to rotary input (side button on watches). As far as I can tell, I can only change the background color. Setting `android:scrollbars` on the `WearableDrawerLayout` does nothing.

I could rewrite everything to use a custom layout which might allow me to add a scrollbar but I would still get rejected on the rotary input.

Not many apps use a `WearableDrawerLayout` anymore (you can't even make one in Compose) which is why I think the testers are unfamiliar with it. It's not deprecated or even discourages from being used.

I tried to post to the Google Support forum but the bureaucrat there didn't understand what I was talking about. The best solution is that someone educate the testers on what a `WearableDrawerLayout` is.